# How to pass arguments to token smart contract generator?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20, constructor

I'm trying to build a 'token generator' smart contract that accepts 3 arguments to then deploy a new token smart contract with those inputs ('strings' for symbol, name, 'address' for owner). I am a total novice, building from a basic escrow example (below), so any help is highly appreciated (!).

Reference: https://medium.com/coinmonks/creating-smart-contracts-with-smart-contract-d54e21d26e00

Example Solidity snippet for 'escrow generator' function:

[image]

So, basically instead of creating a new escrow contract that carries message value everytime someone calls it, I want to make a token generator that spits out an ERC20 with string and address inputs for symbol, name, owner.

Token snippet:

[image]

So, I am wondering what I can do to tweak the generator draft below to accept the these ^^ 3 arguments (_symbol, _name, _owner) that can customize new token smart contract for callers:

[image]

Comment: Just for your information, there a decent number of tutorials for ERC20 Token Factory. Some options include https://embark.status.im/news/2018/10/27/how-to-create-a-token-factory-with-embark-part-2/ (which just generates multiple copies of the same ERC20 contract) OR SOMETHING LIKE https://gist.github.com/critesjosh/e771d52f2b1a1859ab32671650afd665 and/or a really good example at https://medium.com/coinmonks/erc20-token-deployer-fd4b544598ab.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass arguments through.

```
function newContract(string symbol, string name, ...) public ... {
  // must match the constructor inputs for the token implementation
  // assuming "contract ERC20Contract" is imported or visible to the compiler
  ERC20Contract tokenContract = new ERC20Contract(symbol, name, ...);
  contractAddresses.push(address(TokenContract));
  emit ...
  return ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe this worked! Thank you very much for your attention and help here

Comment: Thanks for voting and accepting. Vote hard. Vote often. The StackOverlords track that metric so it helps keep this site alive. :-)